# функция на созданном элементе

Tags: javascript

ДД! Есть такая проблема: я функцией создаю элемент на странице, а другой функцией пытаюсь задать действия созданному элементу:

```
$("#addspoint").click(function() {
    $("#gamecoord").append(itog+'<i class="icon-bucket" id="ssdd"></i> <br>');
});
$("#ssdd").click(function() {
    alert('sdadasd');
});
```

На странице элементы нормально создаются, а вот действия при клике по элементы не происходит. Почему и как это исправить?

Comment: Сделайте fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

```
//эта функция выполняется через 0 милисекунд после загрузки страницы
$("#addspoint").click(function() {
    //это действие выполняется после клика
    $("#gamecoord").append(itog+'<i class="icon-bucket" id="ssdd"></i> <br>');
});

//эта функция выполняется через 1 милисекунду после загрузки страницы
//на этот момент никакого #ssdd на странице не существует
//поэтому клик никуда не привязывается
$("#ssdd").click(function() {
alert('sdadasd');
});
```

Вот как надо:

```
$("#addspoint").click(function() {
    //сначала создали элемент
    $("#gamecoord").append(itog+'<i class="icon-bucket" id="ssdd"></i> <br>');
    //потом привязали к нему листенер
    $("#ssdd").click(function() {
        alert('sdadasd');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы назначаете событие в момент, когда ещё нет элемента. Когда элемент будет создан, нет причин, по которым он бы стал слушать событие.

Привязывайте слушатель события уже после создания элемента.

С минимальными изменениями в вашем коде, надо просто перенести последние три строчки на одну вверх:

```
$("#addspoint").click(function() {
    $("#gamecoord").append(itog + '<i class="icon-bucket" id="ssdd"></i> <br>');

    $("#ssdd").click(function() {
        alert('sdadasd');
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/w1q61txw/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '#ssdd', function() {
  console.log('click');
});
```

Comment: Стоит упомянуть, что это верно для версий jQuery >= 1.7

Comment: Старайтесь писать более детальные ответы. Можно объяснить путь решения, указать на конкретные ошибки, привести ссылки с более подробным разбором проблемы и т. п.

Answer (score 0):

Ну как вариант в копилку решений

```js
$("#addspoint").click(function() {
  var $el = $(itog+'<i class="icon-bucket" id="ssdd"></i> <br>');
  
  $el.on('click', function() {
    console.log('I am here');
  });
  
  $("#gamecoord").append($el);
});
```